API Platform - return predefined array field instead of whole object on PUT
Is there a way to return an array field as a response in the PUT Processor class instead of the whole object like:
public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): array
{
    ...

    $arrayResponse = array_values($this->manager->getInformationArray($account));

    return $arrayResponse;
}

As I am getting:

Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, array given

new Patch(
    uriTemplate: '/account/{id}/info',
    openapiContext: [
        'description' => 'Update the account items',
    ],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['AccountInfo:write']],
    input: AccountItemsDTO::class,
    processor: AccountInformationStateProcessor::class
)

I want to use the method already defined in the processor as it returns the data properly formatted so I would like to skip DTOs on the output attribute.
Would someone be able to help?

I don't think you can return a primitive array, but you could try returning either an ArrayObject or ArrayCollection. I think both are serialized into JSON pretty easily, so that's where I'd start.

ArrayObject indeed solved my problem. Thanks a lot! @maiorano84
